# Bugs since last update (Ubuntu 15.04 - oct 6 2015): nautilus crashes

Tags: updates, 15.04, nautilus, bug-reporting

I made the last update as usually, but after the reboot, I noticed a bug.

**Nautilus freezes**

When I open nautilus, the window just becomes grey and... nothing.

When I call it from terminal, I get this error the first time:

```sh
(nautilus:3934): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:3934): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:3934): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

and the other times:

```sh
** (nautilus:5266): CRITICAL **: nautilus_menu_provider_get_background_items: assertion 'NAUTILUS_IS_MENU_PROVIDER (provider)' failed

** (nautilus:5266): CRITICAL **: nautilus_menu_provider_get_background_items: assertion 'NAUTILUS_IS_MENU_PROVIDER (provider)' failed
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu you are encouraged to please just ask one question at a time, you can ask as many different questions as you like, it  is very unlikely a `nautilus` bug and no sound are related. With regards to your `nautilus` bug a report was filed and they say it is fixed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1429535 Run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to ensure you have the latest `nautilus` packages and reboot, Also please edit this question in to two, so precise answers may be provided

Comment: You rock, after an upgrade, nautilus works like a charm. And next time, I'll create as much questions as needed.

Comment: Glad it helped you, I will write an answer so others can find this information, please stop by and accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a [bug report posted on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1429535) this is fixed in the latest version of `nautilus`, to make sure you have the very latest update available in the repository’s, just open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```